# Temporarily disable autosave in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, autohotkey, google-sheets-offline

I use autohotkey scripts for a lot of things in Google Sheets. It's basically scripted, automated keyboard input. A script may look something like this:

```
Loop, 4
{
    Loop, 7
    {
        Loop, %reps%
        {
            Send, {Enter}
            waitshort()
            Send, {Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Right}{Delete}
            waitshort()
            Send, %nextpage%
            Send, {Enter}
            waitshort()
        }
        Loop, %reps%
        {
            Send, {Up}
            waitshort()
        }
        Send, {Right}
        waitshort()
    }
    Send, {Right}
    waitShort()
}
```

I need it for repetitive tasks that you cannot do with standard Excel tools. The problem is Google Drive saves to cloud every minute or so. Whenever that happens Google Sheets lags for 2–3 seconds and all keyboard inputs are ignored. Which obviously means that the script gets interrupted and further input will be full of errors.

Is there a way to take a Google Sheets document offline for as long as a script is running? I have a script that needs to replace values across several thousand cells.

Comment: Are you aware that [Google shutting down Google Drive for PCs and Macs, to replace it with ‘Drive File Stream’](https://www.thenewsminute.com/article/google-shutting-down-google-drive-pcs-and-macs-replace-it-drive-file-stream-68096) ? For Drive File Stream : You may pause syncing via the menu option of More > Pause Syncing.

Comment: The question is about editing a spreadsheet by using Google Sheets, isn't it? What do you mean by "standard Excel tools"? What do you mean by Google Drive saves to the cloud every minute or so?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable autosave on Google Sheets. Instead of using autohotkey scripts use Google Sheets macros / Google Apps Scripts. For details see [Automate tasks in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?hl=en) and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Regarding using Google Sheets offline, this requires to use Google Chrome. For details see [Work on Google Docs, Sheets, & Slides offline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102?hl=en)